# How to make a hammock?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, cloth-simulation

How do I make an unoccupied hammock like this (just the geometry, no need for netting structure):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify whether you wish to model the hammock (netting, ropes, etc), or whether simpler approaches would be acceptable.  For example you could apply an image texture of the hammock with transparency to a subdivided plane and use cloth simulation.  That would be considerably easier than trying to model and simulate the individual ropes/strands of netting.

Comment: It might be possible to use a cloth simulation applied to a rectangle to get the shape and a procedural pattern to create the webbing.  There are ways to model the rectangle with holes fairly quickly.  Basically you subdivide the rectangle, use the select menu to select a checkerboard pattern and delete the selected faces. There are many cloth simulation tutorials on youtube.

Comment: @risingfall


No need for modelling the actual ropes or netting, I just need to get the right shape/geometry to achieve this.